# How to get value inside <a tag using preg match all?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

i got html content that need to extract values inside hyperlink tag using  preg match all. I tried the following but i don't get any data. I included a sample input data. Could you guys help me fix this code and print all values in front of play.asp?ID=(example: i want to get this value **12345** from play.asp?ID=**12345**) ?

sample input html data:

```
<A HREF="http://www.somesite.com/play.asp?ID=12345&Selected_ID=&PhaseID=123" class="space"><span id="Img_1"></span></A></TD>
```

and the code

```
$regexp = "<A\s[^>]*HREF=\"play.asp(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/A>";

if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) 
{ 


$url=str_replace('?ID=', '', $matches[2]); 

$url2=str_replace('&Selected_ID=&PhaseID=123', '', $url);

print_r($url2);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a full example of what you need (input and result) ?

Comment: thanks for replys . Jbrtrnd i want to get 12345 from ==>play.asp?ID=12345. Note : in my actual input i there are many sets of hyperlink so i want to get all values in front of play.asp?ID=?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '<A HREF="http://www.somesite.com/play.asp?ID=12345&Selected_ID=&PhaseID=123" class="space"><span id="Img_1"></span></A>';

preg_match_all( '/<\s*A[^>]HREF="(.*?)"\s?(.*?)>/i', $str, $match);
print_r( $match );
```

Try out this.

Comment: Thanks that works but gives all href values in html . I am only intrested in those href values that has class name "space" . How i can filter that ?

Comment: `$x = preg_match_all( '/<\s*A[^>]HREF="(.*?)"\s?(.*?)class="space"(.*?)\s*>/i', $str, $match); var_dump( $x ); print_r( $match)`

Comment: if `class="space"` is exist then `$x` return 1 otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1):

Don't! Regular expressions are a (bad) way of text processing. This is not text, but HTML sourcecode. The tools to cope with it are called HTML parsers. Although PHP's DOMDocument is also able to loadHTML, it may glitch on some rare cases. A poorly built regexp (and you are wrong to think there's any other) will glitch on almost any changes in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this enough?

```
/<a href="(.*?)?"/I
```

EDIT:

This seems to work:

```
'/<a href="(.*?)\?/i'
```

Comment: I replaced my regexp with example you gave me but didn't output any result! $regexp = '/<a href="(.*?)\?/i';

Comment: You don't need str_replace. Try '/<a\s[^>]*href=\"(.+)\?/i'.

Answer (score 0):

this should achieve the desired result. it's a combination of an HTML parser and a contents extraction function:

```
function extractContents($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);
    $str = substr($string, $pos);
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
    $extractedContents = trim($str_three);
    return $extractedContents;
}

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://siteyouwantlinksfrom.com');
$links = $html->find('a');
foreach($links as $link)
{
    $playIDs[] = extractContents($link->href, 'play.asp?ID=', '&');
}

print_r($playIDs);
```

you can download `simple_html_dom.php` from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i am getting content using curl but i couldnt get your example to work! i placed the simple_html_dom.php in same folder now no data in text area using curl either!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Regular Expression to parse HTML.

This is a solution with **[DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)** :

```
<?php
    $input = '<A HREF="http://www.somesite.com/play.asp?ID=12345&Selected_ID=&PhaseID=123" class="space"><span id="Img_1"></span></A>';
    // Clean "&" element in href
    $cleanInput = str_replace('&','&amp;',$input);
    // Load HTML

    $domDocument = new DOMDocument();
    $domDocument->loadHTML($cleanInput);

    // Retrieve <a /> tags
    $aTags = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($aTags as $aTag)
    {   

        $href = $aTagA->getAttribute('href');
        $url  =  parse_url($href);
        $vars = array();
        parse_str($url['query'], $vars);

        var_dump($vars);
    }
?>
```

Output :

```
array (size=3)
  'ID' => string '12345' (length=5)
  'Selected_ID' => string '' (length=0)
  'PhaseID' => string '123' (length=3)
```